# Yosemite: Apache 2 installed but no localhost

Tags: macos, apache, svn

My goal is setting up a subversion server on my Yosemite iMac.

Following these [directions](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/)

Status:

1. at terminal prompt, `httpd -v command returns 'Apache/2.4.9'`
2. at terminal prompt, sudo apachectl start returns 'operation already in progress'

But, on issuing URL command `http://localhost` in Safari or Firefox, returns `unable to connect`.

Seems like apache2 server is running, but I cannot proceed.  What do I do?

Comment: Does `ps -Aclw |grep httpd` show any processes running? If not, it's not started. If so, what's in your hosts file (`cat /etc/hosts`)?

You could also try 127.0.0.1 in your browser rather than localhost, if that works the process is running but it's possible that the hosts entry is missing.

Answer (score 0):

> operation already in progress

does **not** mean "Apache started", only "Apache start**ing**" (and for some reason can't finish this task)

You have to check all httpd-related config-files

Comment: Thank you to both.  I issued the command, ps -Aclw |grep httpd.  Nothing was listed after the command, so it's not running.  Being pretty new, please help me by directing me to places which describe how to check the hosts file (cat /etc/hosts). I have a listing of the files in /etc/hosts.  For checking httpd-related config files, how do I proceed?  Thank you.